# using fabric beta testing with react-native expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, google-fabric, fabric-beta

Is there a way I can use [Fabric beta](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/overview.html) testing with react-native expo project ?

I searched all over the internet but didn't find an example of this.

Edit 1: The project has been already created using CRNA command.

PS: I know I can detach from expo then build each project with fabric separately, but detaching process is tedious.

Comment: Besides the answer given, there's also this [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/105) where they state not giving support for fabric in iOS soon, so for now it seems the only way is detaching the project

Answer (score 2):

You need to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html) your app, once detached you can follow the crashlytics iOS [guide](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) with Objective-C, with a difference in the API key step, use the `Info.list` file inside the `Supporting` group, just make sure to delete the old `Fabric` keys already added inside that file.

After that you can use the beta like a normal iOS app, hope this helps you